# UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut, deploying elastic effect ios

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation

I have used the following snippet to make an object animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.2
    options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
    animations:^{[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(faceRight:finished:context:)];
    self.viewMiniDetalhe.center = CGPointMake(500, 150);
}completion:^(BOOL finished){
    NSLog(@"Move to left done");
}];
```

however I would like to implement an elastic effect, known as easeOutElastic.

att,

Comment: What have you tried / researched for that? Why are you using `setAnimationDidStopSelector` inside the animation block - what is wrong with the completion block??

Comment: This block really is correct, I just want to change the style of animation.
putting an elastic effect on arrival

Answer (score 3):

If you are on iOS7, there's the `[UIView animateWithDuration: delay: usingSpringWithDamping: initialSpringVelocity: options: animations: completion:]` class method.
You can animate your view like a spring, and set some extra parameters like damping and initial velocity.

Set `damping < 1.0` to have an elastic behavior. The smaller it is, the springier it feels.

`initialSpringVelocity` is just the speed at launch equal to the distance traveled in one second.

In case you want to know more, [here's the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3ausingSpringWithDamping%3ainitialSpringVelocity%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a).

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0f delay: 0.0f usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5f initialSpringVelocity: 1.0f options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:
{
    myView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, myView.frame.size.width, myView.frame.size.height);
}completion:nil];
```